# File explorer keeps showing icons for some folders

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have Windows 7. I like the detailed list view in Explorer (File explorer). I don't want to see icons ever in my Explorer windows, I only want detailed lists everywhere without fighting regularly.

I managed to set it generally, but when I go to folders that have many images in it, it will switch to large icons view voluntarily. After I saw the large icons, I can switch to detailed list view and it will be remembered for that folder. But then I go to another folder with images and I see icons again. The fight never ends.

How can I get rid of this behavior for good?

Answer (score 0):

> Tools (tab at the top of the folder list may need to press "alt" to see it)
>
> Folder Options
>
> View
>
> Apply to Folders
>
> Apply
>
> Close the Window

[Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/166461-permanent-change-view-win-explorer.html)

Comment: I'm way past that. See the part where "I managed to set it generally, but when..."